ExecuteNonQuery() for a prepared UPDATE query returns 1, but doesn't modify any rows except the first row
Background
We collect data from AzureAD/AD to store in a MySQL database. This is used for reporting purposes.
I have created a Powershell module for working with this MySQL database. I have attempted to make this with prepared statements and parameterized to avoid SQL injection.
I want to re-use the command, otherwise I need to prepare the query with every INSERT/UPDATE, which maxes out the memory on our MySQL server (since the script might be doing 30.000 INSERT/UPDATE operations in a row).
The issue only occurs on UPDATE operations, INSERTs work fine.
Use-case
A Powershell script collects the data from Azure AD, makes a [PSCustomObject] where the property name is the column name for the table in the database, then iterates over each item (e.g. a User) and either INSERTs a new row if it doesn't exist in the database or UPDATEs the user row.
The issue
For UPDATE operations, the first item (user) in the collection is updated correctly, but following UPDATE operations seems successful (return value 1) but no update is performed on the row.
What I've tried so far / Where am I currently in the debugging?
I believe the issue seems to stem from the $this.Command.Parameters.Clear(), but I'm unsure why clearing the parameters causes it to not work after the first run.
I can easily get it to work by preparing the statement before each ExecuteNonQuery(), but that defeats the purpose I am attempting.
I feel like I am missing some key understanding of how the ExecuteNonQuery() and Prepare() is working, which is what's causing it report, incorrectly, that it modified a row. How can it return 1 if no rows were modified?
Mostly, I've really scoured the internet for the last 4 days, and found little help.
When I Prepare() for a selected set of parameters, then change those parameters to identical ones, but with different values, should that cause it to fail?
Powershell script code
The PS code looks like this, although minimized for clarity - I use multiple connections to avoid preparing the query again:
# This part gets the data to upload
$combinedEXOAADAllUsers = New-CombinedAADEXOAllUsers $allUsersBetaData $tenantToConnect

# As the data has maybe 40+ properties, creating the query string is done programmatically
# Looks like: @{ displayName = @displayName, UserPrincipalName = @UserPrincipalName ... }

$insertQuery = New-SQLQueryString -statement "INSERT" -table $MySQLTable -command "SET" -collection $combinedEXOAADAllUsers[0]
$updateQuery = New-SQLQueryString -statement "UPDATE" -table $MySQLTable -command "SET" -collection $combinedEXOAADAllUsers[0] -condition "WHERE $pKey = @$pKey"
        
$MySQLInsert = [MySQLModule]::New($insertQuery, $MySQLAdminPassword)
$MySQLUpdate = [MySQLModule]::New($updateQuery, $MySQLAdminPassword)
$MySQLSelect = [MySQLModule]::New($MySQLAdminPassword)

$MySQLInsert.OpenMySQLConnection()
$MySQLUpdate.OpenMySQLConnection()
$MySQLSelect.OpenMySQLConnection()


foreach ($object in $combinedEXOAADAllUsers) {
# $pKey is the primaryKey on the table, set further in the script
    $primaryKeyValue = $object.$pKey
    $findQuery = "SELECT $pKey FROM $MySQLTable WHERE $pKey = `'$primaryKeyValue`'"
    
    $resultFromDB = Get-MySQLData -query $findQuery -MySQLModule $MySQLSelect
    if (!($resultFromDB)) {
        Invoke-MySQLQuery -collection $object -MySQLModule $MySQLInsert
    } else {
        Invoke-MySQLQuery -collection $object -MySQLModule $MySQLUpdate
    }
}

MySQL module / class
This is the class I've constructed using the MySQL Connector/NET:
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

Class MySQLModule {
    $SQLConnection
    $Command

    MySQLModule([string]$password) {
        $this.SQLConnection = $this.NewMySQLConnection($this.BuildConnectionString($password))
        $this.Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("", $this.SQLConnection) # MySQLCommand type must have a query supplied during instantiation or it does not add the MySQLConnection object
    }

    MySQLModule([string]$PreparedQuery, [string]$password) {
        $this.SQLConnection = $this.NewMySQLConnection($this.BuildConnectionString($password))
        $this.Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($PreparedQuery, $this.SQLConnection) # MySQLCommand created with the prepared query
    }

    [System.Object]BuildConnectionString($password) {
        $stringBuilder = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        $config = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot/config.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

        $stringBuilder.Server = $config.server
        $stringBuilder.Database = $config.database
        $stringBuilder.port = $config.port
        $stringBuilder.UserID = $config.userId
        $stringBuilder.Password = $password

        return $stringBuilder
    }


    [System.Object]NewMySQLConnection([System.Object]$connectionString) {
        $connectionObj = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        $connectionObj.ConnectionString = $connectionString

        return $connectionObj
    }

    OpenMySQLConnection() {
        $this.SQLConnection.Open()
        $this.Command.Connection = $this.SQLConnection
    }

    CloseMySQLConnection() {
        $this.SQLConnection.Close()
    }

    ExecuteNonQuery($parameters) {
        $this.Command.Parameters.Clear()

        foreach ($parameter in $parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
            $this.AddParameter($parameter.Name, $parameter.Value)
        }

        if ($this.Command.IsPrepared -eq $false) {
            $this.Command.Prepare()
        }

        $this.Command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    }

    AddParameter($key, $value) {
        $this.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue($key, $value)
    }

    [System.Data.DataTable]GetDataTable([String]$query) {
        $this.Command.Parameters.Clear()
        $this.Command.CommandText = ""

        $DataAdapter =  New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($this.Command)
        $DataSet =      New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)

        return $DataSet.Tables[0]
    }
}


"which maxes out the memory on our MySQL server" sounds like you are not disposing the connection and command, and judging from the code that seems true. Anyway instead of clearing the parameters why don't you just set them $this.Command.Parameters["param1"] = $someValue;

@Charlieface to clarify, it was maxing out the memory due to spawning 16k+ prepares. I want to dispose the command and connection after uploading all the data.
Anyway, for your proposal, I actually already attempted this, but received some errors, such as:
"Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute" or ""Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'columnName' at row 1".
These errors do not not appear when replacing all the parameters using AddWithValue - Perhaps because the datatype changes (maybe one user has null for a property, but someone else has a not-null value)
